# PNGs in OpenGL?

Tags: opengl, textures, glut

How can I load a PNG into an OpenGL texture?

Comment: See http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenGL_Programming/Intermediate/Textures.

Comment: You may use libpng.
[www.libpng.org/pub/png/libpng.html](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/libpng.html)

Comment: Many libraries can load png files: LodePNG, LibPNG, DevIL, SOIL, are the main ones.

Comment: @Dori; Why did you delete the answer by Dabbler? The links links to a perfectly clear and well written explanation how to load textures and using libpng for loading PNG data as texture.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using:

http://openil.sourceforge.net/

It was originally developed to be used with OpenGL, so everything comes naturally. It supports all the major image formats, including png. I read that in the newer releases they even added a function exactly for people like you:

```
GLuint textureHandle = ilutGLLoadImage("some-picture.jpg");
```

Answer (score 1):

There is also [stb_image](http://www.nothings.org/stb_image.c). Just include the source in your code and you can import JPG,PNG,TGA,BMP,PSD,GIF,HDR, and PIC. It is also entirely public domain.

```
unsigned char * data = stbi_load(FileName.c_str(),&width,&height,&channels,STBI_rgb_alpha);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to patch it for more recent libpng versions, since the last version is from July 2000, but glpng does exactly what you want:

http://libglpng.sourcearchive.com/documentation/1.45/glpng_8c-source.html